# XCode7 Tip: Xcode Command Line Tools are not currently installed, and are required to run Alcatraz

Tags: ios, xcode7, alcatraz

I have installed Alcatraz Plugs to XCode7.0 but when I Clicked:" Window->Package Manager", the XCode tip Me : Xcode Command Line Tools are not currently installed, and are required to run Alcatraz.

Command Line Tools are available for installation in the Downloads section of Preferences.

So, what is this, How to solve this problem, Help ,Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

From your terminal you can type `xcode-select --install` and it will attempt to install the developer tools for you. Then when you open up Xcode the next time you should be all set.

Comment: Actually, I have tried this method, but it no use,I don't know Why .By the way , I have installed two Xcode ,one is XCode5.1  other is XCode7. PS: you can see this :xcode-select: error: command line tools are already installed, use "Software Update" to install updates